# Power BI "Apply query changes" taking unfeasible time to run

Tags: powerbi

I'm using Power BI Desktop to get data from a local SQL Server instance. I have 60+ queries in the Queries pane. Most of them have 1 million+ rows. For reasons that I don't fully understand I'm frequently prompted to "apply query changes". Each time Power BI decides to do this it starts updating all queries, which is simply time unfeasible. I don't know how many hours it would take because it's so slow I have to cancel the process. I've tried changing several Data Load settings but without results. Is there a workaround for this problem? For example an option to do it incrementally, one query at a time? Prompting to apply query changes to *all* queries at once as Power BI does seems unworkable.

Comment: It usually only updates the tables that you've modified the query for and any tables that are dependent on these.